# Not able to add user image in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, laptop, users, system-settings, photo

There is an option to add user image/photograph under User Accounts in System Settings. But whenever I try to add an user image, the system settings freeze and I have to kill it using xkill command. But after that till I restart my computer I can't reopen my system settings.

Please let me know the solution of this problem.

Comment: Have you tried a small photo in `.png` format like [this one](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/6f/Smiley_Face.png)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy: convert your picture (using any picture program like `gimp`) to a square `.png` and save it somewhere where all users have access.

Then use that one in the <kbd>Add User Image</kbd>...

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask